# Dynamically add form fields based on query results

Tags: python, django, forms, django-1.6

I have a model `Question` which holds a list of questions. For the results of querying this table I would like to create a CharField. This is my initial attempt which results in no error, but nothing displayed:

```
def __init__(self, **kwargs):
    super(QuestionnaireForm, self).__init__(**kwargs)
    self.fields['questionnaire'] = dict()
    questions = Question.objects.all()
    for question in questions:
        self.fields['questionnaire']['question' + str(question.pk)] = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs=dict(placeholder=_("Answer"))), label=_(question))
```

And in my template I'm trying:

```
<div class="questionnaire">
    <h2>{% trans "Questionnaire" %}</h2>
    {% if form.questionnaire %}
        {% for question in form.questionnaire %}
            <div class="row">
                {% include "core/includes/field.html" with field=question %}
            </div>
        {% endfor %}
    {% endif  %}
</div>
```

In my rendered output I simply see:

```
<div class="questionnaire">
    <h2>Questionnaire</h2>
</div>
```

If I run `logger.debug(self.fields['questionnaire'])` after setting them in `Form.__init__` I see:

```
DEBUG {'question1': <django.forms.fields.CharField object at 0x7ff76473d550>, 'question3': <django.forms.fields.CharField object at 0x7ff76473d990>, 'question2': <django.forms.fields.CharField object at 0x7ff76473d890>}
```

Comment: Could you show us your display?

Comment: @m170897017 Sorry not sure what you mean, I've added the rendered output and some debug output in case that's what you're referring to. Thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this in your view

```
def myview(request):
    questions = Question.objects.all()
    if request.method == 'POST':

        form = MyForm(request.POST, extra=questions)
        if form.is_valid():
            pass
    else:
        form = MyForm(extra=questions)
        return render(request, "template", { 'form': form})
```

in forms.py

```
class MyForm(forms.Form):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        extra = kwargs.pop('extra')
        super(LoginForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        for question in extra:
            self.fields['question_%s' % extra.id] =  forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput())
```

initial our form with the extra fields that we pass in argument

formsets:for your case you can define another form Question:

```
class QuestionForm(forms.Form):
    question = forms.CharField()
```

view:

```
def myview(request):
    questions_rows = Question.objects.all().count()                      
    QuestionFormSet = formset_factory(QuestionForm,extra=questions_rows)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        myform = LoginForm(request.POST,prefix='myform')
        questions = QuestionFormSet(request.POST,prefix='question')

        if myform.is_valid() and questions.is_valid():
            pass
    else:
        myform = LoginForm(prefix='myform')
        questions = QuestionFormSet(prefix='question')
        return render(request, "template", { 'myform': myform,'questions':questions})
```

you can see that we work with multiple forms (myform simple form and questions is formsets to add question fields dynamically) you can check [formsets](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/formsets/)

Comment: Thanks, your answer looks similar to http://jacobian.org/writing/dynamic-form-generation/ which I just found. The problem is that I have other fields I am specifically outputting in different areas of my template. Would there be a way to specifically choose fields that comply with the field name `question_%s` and loop over them in the template?

Comment: Thanks, used your method, and then in the template `{% for field in form %}{% if "id_question_" in field.auto_id %}...{% endif %}{% endfor %}` helped me pick only the fields I needed.

Comment: glad that it worked out ,i find another solution in forum you can try formset it's more flexible if you want

Comment: Yes please, I'm much too ignorant of formsets!

Comment: formsets is great features in django that can help you very much in feature